# Xcode Simulator using cached files

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running a Cordova app and when I open it using Xcode (iOS Simulator) it shows the updated code files in Project Navigator. I then run `Product -> Clean` and run the code on the simulator but it still uses a previous version of the HTML/JS files.

How do I get the simulator to build again from the updates source files? It seems they are somehow cached and I can't seem to get it cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cordova build ios` first and then run the app in simulator.